# How do I delete an html list item from Redis database using Jade template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, redis, pug

I have a very simple ToDo List app made (following tutorial in comment below) using node.js, express and jade. The app works so I can add items to the list and it saves to the redis database with the id equal to the name of the list item.

Now how can I edit my jade template so a delete button shows up beside the list item, and when I click it, then item will be deleted from the database?

Here is the relevant code:

Routes.js file

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Welcome to JSPlayground Todo' });
};

var redis = require("redis"),
  client = redis.createClient();

exports.todo = function(req, res){ //Pulls items from database to display on page
  var todos = [];
  client.hgetall("Todo", function(err, objs) {
    for(var k in objs) {
      var newTodo = {
        text: objs[k]
      };
      todos.push(newTodo);
    }
    res.render('todo', {
      title: 'New Todo List',
      todos: todos
    });
  });
};

exports.saveTodo = function(req, res) { //Saves a list item from input box to database
  var newTodo = {};
  newTodo.name = req.body['todo-text'];
  newTodo.id = newTodo.name.replace(/ /g, '');
  //console.log(newTodo.id);
  //console.log(newTodo.name);
  client.hset("Todo", newTodo.id, newTodo.name);
  res.redirect("back");
};
```

todo.jade file

```
h1 new todo list
form(action="/save", method="post")
  p
    label Enter a new todo item
    input(type='text',placeholder='new todo', name='todo-text')
  p
    input(type='submit', value='Save')
ul
  each todo in todos
    li #{todo.text}
```

If I make a link on the template page

```
a(href="/del") del
```

and route /del to this function in the routes.js file

```
exports.delTodo = function(req, res) {
  var delTodo = {};
  delTodo.id = "Test";
  client.hdel("Todo", delTodo.id);
  res.redirect("back");
};
```

It will delete a single list item with id of "Test". But I am not sure how to get it to delete the specific list item that was clicked.

Comment: p.s. I am trying to modify the tutorial from http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/06/node-express-todo-app-redis/ to add this new functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
a(href="/del") del
```

to

```
a(href="/del/#{todo.id}") del
```

Make sure that you have express body parser enabled.

```
app.user(express.bodyParser());
```

then modify routes as below

```
app.routes('/del/:todo_id', delTodo);
```

then in the routes.js access this as below.

```
exports.delTodo = function(req, res) {
  var delTodoId = req.params.todo_id;
  client.hdel("Todo", delTodoId);
  res.redirect("back");
};
```

Comment: This is great! I only have one issue, how do I get the delete link a(href="/del/#{todo.id}") del to not render as text inside the li item? If I use 'li #{todo.text}  a(href="/del/#{todo.id}") del' what happens is jade render a(href...) stuff as text

Comment: More concise: how can I nest 'a(href="/del/#{todo.id}") del' inside the li with jade?

Comment: Nevermind got it! I just had to add the link code directly under the li with 2 additional spaces. Your the best, it is now working perfectly! Thanks so much for the help, it is really helping me learn